# disable prettier plugin for specific directory

Tags: prettier

In my typescript & svelte project, I use prettier to format codes.

Also, I use [prettier-plugin-organize-imports](https://github.com/simonhaenisch/prettier-plugin-organize-imports) to automatically organize imports.

However, this plugin does not support svelte yet (it kind of works, but it's buggy), so I want to disable the plugin for *.svelte files while enabling it for *.ts files.

According to the official [doc](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) of prettier, it seems impossible to do this by adding options to config file (prettier.config.js).

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.prettierignore` to exclude files from formatting.

```
# Ignore artifacts:
build
coverage

# Ignore all HTML files:
*.html
```

Check the [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files-prettierignore).

Comment: I want to disable a specific plugin for svelte files, but I want to apply other formatting rules in prettier. Adding svelte files to .prettierignore disables prettier entirely. It is not what I want.

Comment: @compos you can use `--ignore-path`

Comment: Thank you. Let me explain my situation a bit more. I have .svelte files and .ts files in my project. I want to apply basic prettier formatting to **both** .svelte and .ts files, and furthermore, I want to apply prettier-plugin-organize-imports to **only** .ts files. In my understanding, .prettierignore or --ignore-path approach cannot achieve this.

Comment: @compos from the repo, prettier-plugin-organize-imports only support .js, .jsx, .ts, .tsx and .vue files so .svelte aren't affected by the plugin